# How to order by other table?

Tags: sql

I'm working on Stackoverflow-like system for my school project on ASPX. I'm already way beyond what the teacher thought us, so I decided to use the stupid way of counting down and upvotes - Having a spacial table for each vote.

Here are both of my tables:

```
comments
    id | content | by    | bestanswer
    1  | demo    | Vlad  | 0
    2  | sample  | Hagay | 1
    3  | chacking| Gil   | 0
    4  | trying  | Teddy | 0
    ...| ...     | ...   | ...
votes
    postid | username | upvote
    1      | Gil      | 1
    1      | Hagay    | 1
    1      | Teddy    | -1
    2      | Gil      | -1
    3      | Vlad     | -1
    2      | Gil      | 1
    ...    | ...      | ...
```

***How can I, using SQL, SELECT all and set the one with `bestanswer=1` as the first, and then order by the ammount of upvotes (2, 1, 3)?***

Comment: Having a column named upvote with -1 values inspires me to compliment you on your choice of adjectives.

Comment: How are these two tables related? Is Comments.ID = to Votes.PostID? To clarify, are you wanting to select all the fields in the Comments table or all the fields from both tables?

Comment: @mmarie Yes, I want it to order by counting the upvoted (if it is plus so add, if it is a minus so reduce) in all the coulombs in "votes" table with the postid of the id of the coulomb in comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate the "upvotes" in a subquery, then `JOIN` to that table for ordering:

```
SELECT c.*,v.upvotes
FROM comments c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT postid,SUM(upvote) as upvotes
           FROM votes
           GROUP BY postid
           ) v
  ON c.id = v.postid
ORDER BY c.bestanswer DESC, upvotes DESC
```

I'm assuming that `id` and `postid` relate to each other, and that you want to return all fields from the `comments` table, and maybe the total votes as well.

Comment: And if I want to add `WHERE`, I just add it like basic SQL SELECT before `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: `WHERE` goes right above the `ORDER BY`, unless you're trying to filter which votes you tally, in which case it goes before the `GROUP BY`

Comment: But if a comment do not have votes, then it need to be in between the down voted comments and the up voted comments, but it shows them in the bottom.

Comment: @GINCHER Could change `upvotes DESC` to `COALESCE(upvotes,0) DESC` to give those with `NULL` upvotes a `0` instead.